# How to add tinymce editor using jQuery in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce, custom-post-type

I want to adda tinymce editor dynamically using jQuery on wordpress backend in custom post type.

For this I have add following script:

```
var content = '<textarea class="custom-meta-box-textarea" rows="20" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="custom-meta-box-text" id="custom-meta-box-editor"></textarea>';

jQuery('#custom_section').append(content);

var eid = 'custom-meta-box-editor;

tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, eid);
switchEditors.go(eid, 'tmce');
```

It is working and add tinymce editor to textarea, but when I save post then it conflict another editor on custom post page, and after that nothing save.

Is there any script which is missing?

Is there another method to add editor using jQuery?

Comment: if you want to add wordpress like editors for any of meta fields in custom post types you can use `wp_editor` function

Comment: How to use `wp_editor` in jQuery? Can you explain with script?

Comment: you need to do it with jQuery?

Comment: Yes we need to do it with jquery or javascript.